# Login into Mail by using NodeJS with Headless Webdriver

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

Here is a short article demonstration **How to login into Yahoo Mail by using Selenium Web Driver**

http://softwaretestinghelpmanually.blogspot.co.il/2016/02/how-to-login-gmail-with-using-selenium.html

I want to do the same using NodeJS on Linux server with NodJS and a headless webdriver. For some reason I can't find a working set of libraries and make them work together.

Comment: Have you considered using PhantomJS http://phantomjs.org/api/  It is the same idea of a headless browser but development is in JS

Comment: That's totally fine for me that's why I didn't even mention which headless webdriver I want to use. As far I can run it on Linux Server with NodeJS - I am fine with it. I just don't succeed to make it work.